# Delphi - Soap array item value

Tags: delphi, soap, wsdl, delphi-10.1-berlin

I am writing a SOAP webservice client (which is provided by others). I have imported WSDL and called request, servise respondes an XML like below. I can reach (DeliveryNumberList array's item DeliveryNumber) DeliveryNumber's PackingSlipNo and VendorAccount attributes but i need to reach DeliveryNumber's value (008740774). In the class file (which Delphi generated from WSDL) there is no option to reach this value. Someone have any idea?

```
<ns1:Results>
    <ns1:Result>
        <ns1:Status>true</ns1:Status>
        <ns1:Message>Başarılı</ns1:Message>
        <ns1:VendorAccount/>
        <ns1:DeliveryNumberList>
            <ns1:DeliveryNumber PackingSlipNo="X100327233" VendorAccount="0002230728">008740774</ns1:DeliveryNumber>
        </ns1:DeliveryNumberList>
    </ns1:Result>
</ns1:Results>
```

Comment: Show a little MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example)

Comment: wsDelivery is unit which Delphi generated from wsdl. I can reach VendorAccount (Attribute) like below, but unfortunately there is not any option to reach "008740774" value, which is value of (not Attribute) DeliveryNumber

`var
   ADeliveryResponse: DeliveryResponse;
begin
   ...
   ADeliveryResponse := wsDelivery.GetDelivery.sendDelivery(myInput);
   ShowMessage(ADeliveryResponse.Results[0].DeliveryNumberList[0].PackingSlipNo);
   ShowMessage(ADeliveryResponse.Results[0].DeliveryNumberList[0].VendorAccount);
   ADeliveryResponse.Results[0].DeliveryNumberList[0].VendorAccount
end;
`

Answer (score -1):

If you are able to extract the value of VendorAccount, it should be possible to extract also the value of DeliveryNumber.

May be you could show some code how you extract the value of VendorAccount.

PS: can not add comment because not enough reputation, therefore posting as answer

Here is some code that extracts the value from a XML:

```
   myXML.LoadFromFile(FileOpen.FileName);
   memo1.Lines.Add('LocalName:'+myXML.DocumentElement.LocalName);
   nrChildNodes := myXML.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.Count;
   memo1.Lines.Add('ChildNodes:'+inttostr(nrChildNodes) );
   aNode := myXML.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes.FindNode('DeliveryNumberList');
   if aNode <> nil then
      begin
        memo1.Lines.Add('aNode.LocalName:'+aNode.LocalName);
        memo1.Lines.Add('DeliveryNumber='+aNode.ChildValues['DeliveryNumber']);
      end
      else memo1.Lines.Add('aNode = nil');
```

Comment: One of them is attribute and other one is value and Delphi does not generate any thing to reach that value.

Comment: Here is some code that extracts the value from your XML:

Comment: Zehntner, firstly I want to thank you but i am curious about if it is possible to reach the value from Delphi WSDL Importer generated code with some maniplation.

Comment: I think you need to supply more information: what Delphi are you using, what is the original wsdl, with which options did you import the wsdl, what does your code look like (minimal reproducible code).